# Should I forcefully uninstall ubuntu-minimal: Depends: resolvconf as it has unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

My ubuntu software center was not working and I was trying to fix it.
I ran the following series of commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

This one failed and this was the result

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                             

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                     

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease  

W: F ailed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:3128:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then i ran these commands

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

and when I ran the command `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I got the following result:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `'apt-get -f install'` to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-minimal : Depends: resolvconf
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f."
```

So should I forcefully uninstall **ubuntu-minimal : Depends: resolvconf**

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get install -f` command?

Comment: as Raj said , near problem happen for me too I try that and solved

Comment: i did run sudo apt-get install -f but it failed E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what message `sudo apt-get update` failed with. Telling us "it failed" is not very useful.

Comment: sudo apt-get install resolvconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  resolvconf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 251 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main resolvconf all 1.69ubuntu1.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1

Answer (score 0):

I tend to not use/trust `sudo autoremove` as I have found that when I look at the packages it says are no longer required, I have seen my entire desktop, (when using the MATE desktop), and have experiences with it removing dependencies that I did in fact require, and have had to reinstall some systems as a result, always look at what packages it's removing when you issue that command, because it may have even removes a repository gpg key, and now the install -f wont work because the system wont download from the untrusted repo.

Just the type experiences I have had with the autoremove.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are going the wrong way about this. You should instead install `resolvconf` with `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`. Removing `ubuntu-minimal` can leave your system unbootable.

Comment: I tried  sudo apt-get install resolvconf  but that too failed

Comment: @user283501 edit your question and add the result.